# What algorithm use for random forests?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification, random-forest

i am working on my master's thesis. I have some data and i need find some algorithm whitch must tell me if this data represents brain or not. I have same train data where i know whether it is brain or not. I would like use random forests for that, but i dont know if is best for this case. Can you suggest me some algorithm for random forests or something better?

Comment: this is too vague a question; you need to give a specific programming problem.

Comment: You have a classification problem. There's a plethora of classification algorithms in machine learning and artificial intelligence, you need to provide more information to make it possible to give you an answer.